# Python 3 weighted random choice function memoized version

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, random, memoization

I have written a function that randomly picks one element from a set with different probabilities for each element, anyway it takes a dictionary as argument, the keys of the dictionary are the choices and can be of any type, the values of the dictionary are weights and must be non-zero integers. It randomly chooses a choice based on weights and returns the choice.

I have tried a bunch of different methods and used the most efficient method I have found in this implementation, I intend to call the function with same arguments repeatedly and the dictionaris aren't supposed to change during execution, so I thought memoization would be a good idea, so I did memoize it - using a `dict`, and the performance improvement is huge, as expected.

### Code

```py
import random
from bisect import bisect
from itertools import accumulate
from typing import Any

cache = dict()

def weighted_choice(dic: dict) -> Any:
    mark = id(dic)
    if mark not in cache:
        if not isinstance(dic, dict):
            raise TypeError('The argument of the function should be a dictionary')
        
        choices, weights = zip(*dic.items())
        if set(map(type, weights)) != {int}:
            raise TypeError('The values of the argument must be integers')
        if 0 in weights:
            raise ValueError('The values of the argument shouldn\'t contain 0')
        
        accreted = list(accumulate(weights))
        cache[mark] = (choices, accreted)
    
    else:
        choices, accreted = cache[mark]
    
    chosen = random.random() * accreted[-1]
    return choices[bisect(accreted, chosen)]
```

### Example

```py
LETTER_FREQUENCY = {
    "a": 80183,
    "b": 17558,
    "c": 42724,
    "d": 28914,
    "e": 100093,
    "f": 11308,
    "g": 20298,
    "h": 24064,
    "i": 80469,
    "j": 1440,
    "k": 6103,
    "l": 52184,
    "m": 28847,
    "n": 63640,
    "o": 64730,
    "p": 29325,
    "q": 1741,
    "r": 66553,
    "s": 54738,
    "t": 63928,
    "u": 34981,
    "v": 8877,
    "w": 6020,
    "x": 2975,
    "y": 19245,
    "z": 2997
}
weighted_choice(LETTER_FREQUENCY) # returns a letter and the bigger the weight the more likely the letter will be returned
```

### Performance

```py
#nonmemoized
In [57]: def weighted_choice(dic: dict) -> Any:                          
    ...:     choices, weights = zip(*dic.items())                        
    ...:     accreted = list(accumulate(weights))                        
    ...:     chosen = random.random() * accreted[-1]                     
    ...:     return choices[bisect(accreted, chosen)]                    
                                                                         
In [58]: %timeit weighted_choice(LETTER_FREQUENCY)                       
4.03 µs ± 293 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

#memoized
In [59]: cache = dict()
    ...:
    ...: def weighted_choice(dic: dict) -> Any:
    ...:     mark = id(dic)
    ...:     if mark not in cache:
    ...:         if not isinstance(dic, dict):
    ...:             raise TypeError('The argument of the function should be a dictionary')
    ...:         choices, weights = zip(*dic.items())
    ...:         if set(map(type, weights)) != {int}:
    ...:             raise TypeError('The values of the argument must be integers')
    ...:         if 0 in weights:
    ...:             raise ValueError('The values of the argument shouldn\'t contain 0')
    ...:         accreted = list(accumulate(weights))
    ...:         cache[mark] = (choices, accreted)
    ...:     else:
    ...:         choices, accreted = cache[mark]
    ...:     chosen = random.random() * accreted[-1]
    ...:     return choices[bisect(accreted, chosen)]

In [60]: %timeit weighted_choice(LETTER_FREQUENCY)
702 ns ± 25.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

I want to know how to properly implement the memoization, in this function there are two properties that need to be remembered for each input, assuming the variables will never change which in practice is true; The properties are `choices` and `accreted` (the accumulated weights), they are unique to each input, determined by the inputs and won't change.

However the function is non-deterministic, it should return different outputs for same inputs, there is one and only one non-deterministic variable, the `chosen` variable, and the output is determined by the random variable.

The only memoization technique I know of is `functools.lrucache` decorator and the functions wrapped by it return same outputs for same inputs which is obviously not suitable here, unless I write a helper function that processes the inputs which as you see consists the bulk of the function, I think this is excessive and Python function calls are expensive.

So what is the proper way to memoize the function?

Comment: The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id) state: *Two objects with non-overlapping lifetimes may have the same id() value*. This might cause bugs in your current implementation in some (probably rare) cases.

Comment: Why not use the `p` argument to numpy's [choice](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.Generator.choice.html#numpy.random.Generator.choice) ?

Comment: @Reinderien Actually I have tested that, and even with memoization, generating a single output costs about 44 microseconds, the overhead of numpy is simply too high, however if I use the same argument to get samples in batch it is indeed faster than the running the iteration one in batch, however I need to sample one element from each distribution, adjacent calls will have different arguments and the distributions are reused very frequently...

Comment: OK, but you don't show this reuse or your outer loop. Please show all of your code.

Comment: What makes you think your current implementations is not proper? As you pointed out, the function is non-deterministic, so it can't be cached.  However, there are expensive calculations that can be cached.  It looks like a reasonable implementation.

Comment: Why not write a `FrequencyDict` class with a `.choice()` method instead? It looks like you want a special method for a particular type of dict.

Comment: You might be interested in [this method](https://lips.cs.princeton.edu/the-alias-method-efficient-sampling-with-many-discrete-outcomes/).

Answer (score 1):

I'd prefer a separation between "distribution objects" and sampling.

```py
class WeightedDiscrete:
    def __init__(self, weighted_items: dict):
        if not isinstance(weighted_items, dict):
            raise TypeError('The argument of the function should be a dictionary')

        items, weights = weighted_items.keys(), weighted_items.values()
        
        if any(not isinstance(w, int) for w in weights):
            raise TypeError('The values of the argument must be integers')
        if any(w <= 0 for w in weights):
            raise ValueError('The values of the argument be less than 0')

        self.items = list(items)
        self.accreted = list(accumulate(weights))

    def choice(self):
        chosen = random.random() * self.accreted[-1]
        return self.items[bisect(self.accreted, chosen)]
```

Given that, you can manage caching the `WeightedDiscrete` object given different `weighted_items` separately, and the cache design becomes an orthogonal problem.

`lru_cache` unfortunately still won't work, since dicts are unhashable, but for the specific use a custom id-based cache might be appropriate:

```py
class IdCache:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cache = dict()

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.cache[id(key)] = value
        
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.cache[id(key)]
        
    def __contains__(self, key):
        return id(key) in self.cache
    

cache = IdCache()

def get_distribution(weighted_items):
    if weighted_items not in cache:
        w = WeightedDiscrete(weighted_items)
        cache[weighted_items] = w

    return cache[weighted_items]
```

In case you have a lot of different distributions, the `WeightedDiscrete` class could perhaps be further optimized by inheriting form a named tuple to reduce space.